# Searching for aov effect tables with minimum values in R

Tags: r, anova

After doing Analysis of variance and and building effects table, I need to capture only 5 of those term's table with minimum values. Because of a long list of factors; as there are around 100 factors starting from x1 to x100, I am unable to visualize all the tables.

```
model<-aov(y~., data=data)
effects<-model.tables(model, "effects")
```

The label names of any term's table is

```
names(effects$tables$x1)
"1"      "2"
```

I need to capture only 2 of those term's tables with minimum value for label "2".

Question edited:

```
effects$tables[1:4]   
$x1
x1
      1           2 
-0.01099232  0.01053045 

$x2
x2
      1           2 
-0.03292931  0.03321318 

$x3
x3
     1          2 
0.2881996 -0.3008399 

$x4
x4
       1            2 
-0.010151743  0.009236422
```

The results may be -0.3008399 and 0.009236422, if we select only 2 minimum values out of the 4 above given tables.

Comment: This question is very unclear, whatdoe you mean by `minimum value for label "2"` what value?

Comment: @mnel. I have edited the question. As can be seen there are effects for each level. I want to capture the effect for level 2 but only those term tables with first 5 minimum values OR lets say if we sort all these term tables then the first 5 ones OR the ones which are most significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps: (untested in absence of reproducible example)

```
eff2 <- effects$tables$x1[['2']]
eff2[ order(eff2) ][1:5]
```

Or perhaps (still untested in conitnued absence of example)

```
efftabls <- sapply(eff2, '[', 2)
head( efftabls[order(efftabls)], 5)  # 5 used to be the number requested
```

Comment: But, this example is only using x1 term. I have around 100 terms i.e from x1 to x100 or effects$tables[1:100]. I need to determine those terms with minimum values; May be 5 minimum values in 5 term tables.